# How can we restart the Kubernetes pod if its readiness fail

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

a quick question. I know if the Kubernetes liveness probe fails, kubernetes will help restart the pod and try again. But how about the readiness probe fails? How can I also ask kubernetes to restart the pod?

`api-group-0                     0/1       Running     0          6h35m`

Restart this pod can make it works. Thanks all!

Comment: Can you add your pod spec to the question?  Do you already have a different liveness probe for the same pod?

Comment: What is your readiness probe checking for  ? Is it different than your liveness . If your pod not being ready is just a temporary situation ( which is what readiness probe is normally used for ) then you might want the traffic not to be redirected at your pod for that period, if this temporary becomes a permanent thing , then it is not really a readiness but a liveness issue..

Comment: Hi David and fatcook, Thanks!
I have both liveness and readiness

        livenessProbe: ~

        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - "/opt/fissile/readiness-probe.sh"
            - "curl --silent --fail --head http://${HOSTNAME}:9022/v2/info"

Right now, some times my readiness fail because "/opt/fissile/readiness-probe.sh" is executed with error. I would like to restart the pod if the readiness fail.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to trigger pod restart within a readiness probe.
As it was recommended in the comments, you should rely on liveness probe instead.

```
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /opt/fissile/readiness-probe.sh
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 10
      failureThreshold: 3
```

If you have concerns about readiness-probe.sh fails periodically and shouldn't trigger restart straight after the first failure, consider `failureThreshold` setting. It will give this many tries before pod restart.